# Python-docx header / footer error

Tags: python-2.7, python-docx

```
from docx import Document

d = Document('/tmp/doc_with_header.docx')

d.sections[0].headers[0].add_paragraph(text='moar header')
d.save('/tmp/moar_headers.docx')
```

this is the code 
here is the error

```
AttributeError: 'Section' object has no attribute 'header'
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like, you've got this solution from [this](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/header.html) page, yeah? Unfortunately, it's not the actual documentation, but only API suggestion, for further implementation. Just promises and nothing more at the moment=\